# android_camera_tutorial

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

why when i run the debuggern on android_camera_tutorial when trying to pas over this line I get an error on my application running. startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, MasterChooser.class), 0);

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29025/android_camera_tutorial/) by [vahid](https://answers.ros.org/users/1777/vahid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to fix it by commenting out this line out.

---

Originally posted by [vahid](https://answers.ros.org/users/1777/vahid/) with karma: 31 on 2012-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0